# how to datepart from time to time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, t-sql

How do check if current time exists from stated time to time ? I have the statement below, so say I want 9:30 to 10:30, it won't work, this would work if it's 9:30 to 10. but not 9:30 to 10:30.

How do I go about it ?

```
if datepart(hour, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 
(9) and (10) and
datepart(minute, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 
(30) and (30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use times:

```
where convert(time, current_timestamp) between '09:30:00' and '10:30:00'
```